# Need Some Assistance getting music to play in the background automatically when the browser page loads

Tags: javascript, html

I am making an online personal portfolio and I would like to have music play in the background when the page is loaded. However, I cannot seem to get it to work. The button to turn the music on definitely works and if I reload the page after I have already typed it into the browser the music plays automatically but not when the page is first loaded. I have attached the code that I am working with below. If anyone has any ideas it would be much appreciated!

```
$('body').append('<audio loop autoplay volume="0" id="audio-player"><source src="username.github.io/html/music/PortfolioAudioRuby.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>');
        var audio = document.getElementById("audio-player");
        audio.volume = 0.2;


    if($(window).length) {
        $('.music-bg').css({'visibility':'visible'});
        $('body').addClass("audio-on");
        if ($('body').hasClass('audio-off')) {
            $('body').removeClass('audio-on');
        } 
        $(".music-bg").on('click', function() {
            $('body').toggleClass("audio-on audio-off");         
            if ($('body').hasClass('audio-off')) {
                audio.pause();
            } 
            if ($('body').hasClass('audio-on')) {
                audio.play();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: _"I would like to have music play in the background when the page is loaded"_ Please, please don't.

Comment: Most web browsers are cracking down on this, actually. It's becoming very hard, and in some cases impossible, to automatically play audio, video, enter fullscreen, etc, without some form of manual user input. Autoplay has been cancer on the web since MySpace anyway, please re-consider.

Comment: Chrome, maybe other browsers, disable autoplaying sound now, and for good reason.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the info everyone!